# Bootstrapping an ASP.NET Core 2.1 application containing multiple module types using DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Started building the infrastructure for a multi-tenant ASP.NET Core 2.1 application which is and will be composed of many modules.

The idea is to enable any modules which are to be added in the future, to be just plugged into the system, registering their own required dependencies on app startup and using the already registered dependencies (dependencies registered by other modules) if needed.

Let's first take a look at the sample code of how I imagined this would look like - from the top of my head.
Let's say we've got some kind of a module manager which we're gonna name just that - `ModuleManager`.

```
public class ModuleManager
{
    // Let's store all of our module types here
    private List<Type> moduleTypes;

    void RegisterModules(Type webHostModuleType, IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Find all module dependencies recursively 
        // (i.e. all modules that are specified in some, let's say 'DependsOn' attribute
        // which decorates webHostModuleType)
        moduleTypes = FindDependencies();

        // Now we need to register all dependencies
        foreach (Type moduleType in moduleTypes)
        {
            services.AddSingleton(moduleType);
        }

        // ... and we shouldn't forget to register the webHostModuleType too
        services.AddSingleton(webHostModuleType);
    }
}
```

Let's stop there for now and first define the module type. I think it is expected to presume that each module type can have different properties and fields based on their needs, but we will have to make all of them derive from a base module type. Let's call it `BaseModule` and this is how I imagined it to be:

```
public abstract class BaseModule
{
    // I've currently got no idea on how this method should be defined
    // Because it's supposed to register the concrete module's dependencies
    // after the module has been instantiated... is that even possible?
    // Should it be some kind of a factory method rather than void 
    // and serve as a lazy initializer? Is that also even possible?
    // Something that should make use of IOptions<>?
    public virtual void Init()
    {
    }

    // Maybe some post-init code will be needed too
    public virtual void PostInit()
    {
    }
}
```

And then we will have some concrete module types defined like this:

```
public class CoreModule : BaseModule
{
    // some dependencies that need to be injected...
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment;

    private readonly IDontKnowSomeOtherDependency someOtherDependency;

    public CoreModule(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment, IDontKnowSomeOtherDependency someOtherDependency)
    {
        this.hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        this.someOtherDependency = someOtherDependency;
    }

    public override void Init()
    {
        // Somehow register additional services defined by this module,
        // after it's been instantiated
    }
}
```

And let's say, for the completeness sake, our `webHostModuleType` is defined like this:

```
[DependsOn(typeof(CoreModule))]
public class WebHostModule : BaseModule
{
    private readonly ISomeDependencyRegisteredInCoreModule someDependency;

    public WebHostModule(ISomeDependencyRegisteredInCoreModule someDependency)
    {
        this.someDependency = someDependency;
    }

    public override void Init()
    {
        // Register some other service based on something from 'someDependency' field
    }
}
```

And finally, let's go back to the module manager. Now it should have another method, executed after `RegisterModules`, which should instantiate each module in the correct order and then call `Init()` and `PostInit()` in the correct order, starting with the `CoreModule` and ending with `WebHostModule`. Something akin to this:

```
public void(?) LoadModules()
{
    // Sort our modules first so dependencies come in first and webHostModuleType the last
    SortEm(moduleTypes);

    // Now we need to instantiate them. 
    // Can't do it manually as all of them might have different constructors
    // So need to do it using our service collection 
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServicePRovider();

    foreach (Type moduleType in moduleTypes)
    {
        BaseModule moduleInstance = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(moduleType) as BaseModule;

        // This is where we can register everything needed by the module instance. 
        // But can we?
        moduleInstance.Init();
        moduleInstance.PostInit();
    }

    // Maybe return the IServiceProvider instance we've built 
    // so we can return in to the `ConfigureServices` and return to ASP.NET Core from there?
}
```

As you can see, this approach raises many questions. Am I going in the right direction at all? Is there a way to register services from withing modules' `Init()` and `PostInit()` methods correctly?

If I call `BuildServiceProvider()` and then instantiate singleton instances, I would have to return that `IServiceProvider` instance back to `ConfigureServices()` so ASP.NET Core can use it. If I don't, it will build a new one and then all these singletons will be instantiated again.

But if I call `ConfigureServices()` then I won't be able to add new services, which I have to do after modules have been instantiated. What is the approach, if it's possible at all? Any opinions, ideas?

Wow such wall of text, thanks for reading at all!

Answer (score 0):

Well, just one more opinion, but we are using the same standard ad the Net Core team, creating extension methods, so we just need to add the services were they are required:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddVtaeCommonServices();
        services.AddMyServiceMX(Configuration);
        services.AddOtherService(Configuration);

        return VtaeConfig.ConfigVtae(services);
    }
}
```

With this extension methods for example:

```
public static class CommonServicesExtension
{

    public static IServiceCollection AddVtaeCommonServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddNodaDateTime();
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddScoped<AuthorizedIpFilter>();
        services.AddScoped<HttpContextManager>();
        services.AddTransient<ProspectService>();
        services.AddTransient<TokenService>();
        services.AddTransient<TokenGenerator>();
        services.AddTransient<ProspectsRepository>();
        services.AddSingleton<UniqueIDGenerator>();
        services.AddSingleton<SchedulerService>();
        services.AddSingleton<ChecksumService>();
        return services;
    }
}
```

This way we can extract our functions to nuget packages and then simply re utilize them by adding the `AddXXXService()` in our startup